# How to keep server running on EC2 after ssh is terminated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance on which I installed rails server. The server also runs fine when I do

```
rails server
```

But after I close the ssh connection the server also stops. How can I keep the server running even after closing the ssh connection.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
screen rails s
```

did the trick

after that CTRL + A + D and I left and the server is running fine

Answer (score 10):

Try this. We have to start rails server as daemon.

```
rails s -d &
```

Comment: as daemon ?? can you elaborate?

Comment: A daemon is a type of program on Unix-like operating systems that runs unobtrusively in the background, rather than under the direct control of a user, waiting to be activated by the occurance of a specific event or condition.

Comment: I did as you told. Still I can't manage the server to work after I close the ssh connection

Comment: check rails servers is working or not using "ps -aux | grep rails" in ssh.

Comment: I think it should be "rails s -d&" instead of "rails -s -d&" , to also specify environment(say production for this example), use "rails s -d -e production&"

Comment: Also note that the process id of the server process can be found in {rails app directory}/tmp/pids/server.pid , this id is useful when you want to terminate the server process later

Comment: @vajapravin And how can we stop it?

Comment: What does the `&` do?

Comment: Appending ` &` to the end of any command executes that command in background @ingh.am

Answer (score 1):

run at as server means thu nginx or apache or what ever this development server not mean run as server 
user this is need more info https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-rails-and-nginx-with-passenger-on-ubuntu
also if want advance sololtion use rubber https://github.com/rubber/rubber

Answer (score 1):

I needed mine running everything not, just rails in the background. Install Screen which makes a sub terminal that isn't affected by your ssh connection. `sudo apt-get install screen` Open screen `screen` Then start rails `rails server &`.

Press 'Crtl + A' then 'D' to escape and type `screen -r` to get back in to the screen terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend using apache or something else instead of the regular rails server but you can probably add & at the end and feel free to leave

```
rails server &
```

Comment: this will be dead when he close at the term keep in mind its good for background pros.

Answer (score 0):

These steps worked for me. MY OS is Description:    **Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS**

- `sudo apt-get install screen`
- `screen rails s`
- `CTRL + A + D` **from terminal to detached the existing process and let it run**.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a production proof version using RVM and Systemd. Will keep the server alive if it gets terminated for any reason.

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma Control
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=user
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/your_project_name

PIDFile=/var/www/your_project_name/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid

ExecStart=/home/user/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec puma -C /var/www/your_project_name/shared/puma.rb --daemon

ExecStop=/home/user/.rvm/bin/rvm default do bundle exec pumactl -S /var/www/your_project_name/shared/tmp/pids/puma.state -F /var/www/your_project_name/shared/puma.rb stop

Restart=always
# RestartSec=10

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```